# quiero agregar mas usuarios a mi base de datos pero no puedo debido al error "Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY"

Tags: php, mysql

quiero agregar mas usuarios así como los valores que se muestran en el codigo pero al momento de querer agregar un nuevo usuario me lanza el siguiente error "Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY" ya revise mi base de datos y no se esta utilizando un id ya existente esta declarado en la base de datos como llave principal "numerodecuenta"

```dart
    <?php

include 'conexion.php';

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$calle=$_POST['calle'];
$colonia=$_POST['colonia'];
$codigopostal=$_POST['codigopostal'];
$fechalimitedepago=$_POST['fechalimitedepago'];
$montoapagar=$_POST['montoapagar'];
$cuenta=$_POST['cuenta'];
$pagodomiciliado=$_POST['pagodomiciliado'];
$ruta=$_POST['ruta'];
$numerodemedidor=$_POST['numerodemedidor'];
$suministroirregular=$_POST['suministroirregular'];
$cumplido=$_POST['cumplido'];
$grupovulnerable=$_POST['grupovulnerable'];
$fechadelecturaanterior=$_POST['fechadelecturaanterior'];
$viviendas=$_POST['viviendas'];
$locales=$_POST['locales'];
$tipousuario=$_POST['tipousuario'];
$lecturaanterior=$_POST['lecturaanterior'];
$lecturaactual=$_POST['lecturaactual'];
$consumo=$_POST['consumo'];
$diametro=$_POST['diametro'];
$basecalculo=$_POST['basecalculo'];
$anomalia=$_POST['anomalia'];
$numerodecuenta=$_POST['numerodecuenta'];

$consulta="insert into servicio_db values('".$nombre."','".$calle."','".$colonia."','".$codigopostal."','".$fechalimitedepago."','".$montoapagar."','".$cuenta."','".$pagodomiciliado."','".$ruta."','".$numerodemedidor."','".$suministroirregular."','".$cumplido."','".$grupovulnerable."','".$fechadelecturaanterior."','".$viviendas."','".$locales."','".$tipousuario."','".$lecturaanterior."','".$lecturaactual."','".$consumo."','".$diametro."','".$basecalculo."','".$anomalia."','".$numerodecuenta."')";

mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```dart
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 27-11-2020 a las 04:18:52
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.14-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.4.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `op`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `servicio_db`
--

CREATE TABLE `servicio_db` (
  `nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `calle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `colonia` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `codigopostal` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `fechalimitedepago` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `montoapagar` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cuenta` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pagodomiciliado` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ruta` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numerodemedidor` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `suministroirregular` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cumplido` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `grupovulnerable` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fechadelecturaanterior` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `viviendas` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `locales` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `tipousuario` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lecturaanterior` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lecturaactual` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `consumo` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `diametro` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `basecalculo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `anomalia` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numerodecuenta` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `servicio_db`
--

INSERT INTO `servicio_db` (`nombre`, `calle`, `colonia`, `codigopostal`, `fechalimitedepago`, `montoapagar`, `cuenta`, `pagodomiciliado`, `ruta`, `numerodemedidor`, `suministroirregular`, `cumplido`, `grupovulnerable`, `fechadelecturaanterior`, `viviendas`, `locales`, `tipousuario`, `lecturaanterior`, `lecturaactual`, `consumo`, `diametro`, `basecalculo`, `anomalia`, `numerodecuenta`) VALUES
(' MARTINEZ ', 'CLUB ALPINO', 'CARDENAS, '55555', '21 JUL 20', '$ 413.00 ', '1525357', 'NO', '0701451089', 11002041, ' (-) $ 0.00', ' (-) $ 0.00', ' (-) $ 0.00', '07 ABR 20', 2, 0, 'DP', '0', 0, 27, '13', 'PROMEDIO ESTANDAR', 'DOMICILIO CERRADO', '1525357');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `servicio_db`
--
ALTER TABLE `servicio_db`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`numerodecuenta`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

aqui se muestra como llave primaria "numerodecuenta" como les comento me sale el error antes mencionado segun yo no estoy repitiendo datos en cuanto a la llave primaria ya que este campo lo estoy llenando por el momento al azar por cuestión de pruebas.

Comment: Y estaras mandando un numero de cuenta que ya existe? mostra el describe de tu tabla, y los datos que tratas de insertar y fijate si efectivamente no existen...

Comment: Estas enviando una clave repetida, Muestra la estructura de la base de datos para saber cual columna es.

Comment: Si tienes un campo por ejemplo ID que no es autonumérico, debes especificarlo en el sql, en tu caso, parece que no es autonumérico y toma siempre el mismo valor, prueba a añadir el campo en tu cláusula insert o hazlo autonumérico en la base de datos. El problema ocurre porque hay un campo definido como PRIMARY en la base de datos y por tanto, debe ser único para cada registro, puede que no lo estés incluyendo en la SQL o que tome un valor por defecto que es siempre el mismo.

Comment: Revisando, veo que tu campo primario es numerodecuenta y no id, por lo que está claro que cuando haces el insert, estás insertando un campo duplicado ya que lo incluyes en la SQL del insert. Tienes varias opciones, una es comprobar antes de insertar si existe el numerodecuenta en otro registro y de ser así, mostrar el error adecuado, otra forma sería capturar el error de duplicado y mostrar el error. En cualquier caso, si defines un campo como primary, no puede estar duplicado.

Comment: gracias ya encontré mi error al parecer a pesar de que estoy asignando como llave primaria "numrodecuenta" tengo otro apartado llamado "cuenta" en el cual igual se meten os mismos valores asignados en el campo de "numerodecuenta" por lo que me genera ese error Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes compartir el sql de tu tabla por favor.
sin embargo tu campo de primary key debe ser auto_increment

```
`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

Comment: porque solamente se piensa en id autoincrementables? (no esta mal, pero no es la unica solucion...) mejor esperar a que OP conteste lo que se le pregunto...

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que la columna que esta asiganada la llave primaria (Primary Key) este habilitado el incremento automatico, por alli debe ir el problema;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque solamente se piensa en id autoincrementables? (no esta mal, pero no es la unica solucion...) mejor esperar a que OP conteste lo que se le pregunto...